# Asking for feedback on a meeting summary

Tags: writing, sentence

I've got to write a meeting summary, and amongst the recipient will be my boss. To ensure that I was accurate, I would like to ask for feedback from my recipient. I've got the following sentence:

> In case of omission or mistake, please contact me.

The problem is that this sentence doesn't quite please me. I would have liked to use the word *correction* instead of *mistake*, but then it wouldn't have been in the same level, as there is *omissions* but there is a "need for corrections". Furthermore I don't like the "please contact me" although I don't have a better way to say what I want. I don't want to be contacted as much as I want any mistakes to be pointed to me.

It's at that point that I thought to myself, that there could be a standard formulation for such request. So first I would like to now, in a formal and polite context, would my sentence fit with my intent? And second, is there any standard formulation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I don't like about your sentence is that it sounds a bit negative - as if you expected omissions or mistakes to be found.

A more *positive* way of communicating the same message would be something like:

> Let me know if you have any questions or comments.

"Questions or comments" sounds more positive because these words do not necessarily relate to mistakes. It shows that you expect questions or feedback in general - positive or negative feedback.

Comment: +1. If you want to be even more polite you could start "Please let me know...".

Comment: I would say something like, "Please let me know if I missed anything."  I tend to write more conversationally (but still professionally) in work emails, etc. because I think it's more easily understandable and disarming that way. I can still write bloated legalese and business speak with the best of them when the situation calls for it.

Comment: Please, is it correct or polite to write: "should you have any suggestions, please let me know" or even: "should you have any questions or comments, please let me know" ?

Answer (score 8):

My standard phrase is:

> If you have any questions or comments, just let me know.

Of course, that's a one-size-fits-all no-brainer, and comes off as such. But then again, I know that if I start thinking about it, I will start overthinking, and writing a simple three-sentence email *will take forever*.

That being said, I can certainly think of a few variations. For the first part of the sentence, I might write:

> - If there are any omissions or mistakes,..
> - If something's wrong or incomplete,..
> - If you have any suggestions or corrections to make,..

And for the second part, I might write (depending on the level of formality):

> - ... please do not hesitate to let me know.
> - ... please let me know.
> - ... just let me know.
> - ... just drop me a note.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to keep your sentence rather short, here are a few suggestions:

- I welcome comments, suggestions and corrections.
- Please send me any comment, suggestion or correction you may have.
- Please feel free to relay your comments, suggestions or corrections.
- If you find errors or inaccuracies in this summary, please report them to me.
- A revised summary will communicated if any error or inaccuracy is reported to me.

“*Report ... to me*” might be a solution to your dislike of “*contact me*”, as it makes the purpose of the contact more explicit.